# NTFS ACL Inheritance is not correctly retrieved for some files

Tags: winapi, permissions, acl, file-permissions, ntfs

I noticed that my application is not retrieving correctly the NTFS ACL 
inheritance of certain files. The files are located in subfolders of my 
profiles. When using ICACLS.EXE it correctly outputs (I) for those files. But 
when retrieving `ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE->Header.AceFlags` using `GetFileSecurity()` this is always zero for those files. However, this is working for many other 
files on my system. Also folders are not affected, but all files in my profile 
directory and its subfolders.

Here is sample C++ code that allows to reproduce the problem:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <comdef.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, TCHAR** argv)
{
    // Check Input Arguments
    if (2 != argc)
    {
        // Output usage information in case of wrong arguments
        cout << "Usage: ACLInfo.exe <path to file or directory>" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Get the path from supplied arguments
    _bstr_t strPath = argv[1];

    // Find out size of needed buffer for security descriptor with DACL
    // DACL = Discretionary Access Control List
    DWORD dwSizeNeeded = 0;
    BOOL bSuccess = GetFileSecurityW(strPath,
                                DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                                NULL,
                                0,
                                &dwSizeNeeded);

    if (0 == dwSizeNeeded)
    {
        return E_FAIL;
    }
    BYTE* pSecDescriptorBuf = new BYTE[dwSizeNeeded];

    // Retrieve security descriptor with DACL information
    bSuccess = GetFileSecurityW((BSTR)strPath,
                                DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                                pSecDescriptorBuf,
                                dwSizeNeeded,
                                &dwSizeNeeded);

    // Check if we successfully retrieved security descriptor with DACL 
information
    if (!bSuccess)
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        cout << "Failed to get file security information (" << dwError << ")\n";
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    // Getting DACL from Security Descriptor
    PACL pacl;
    BOOL bDaclPresent, bDaclDefaulted;
    bSuccess = 
GetSecurityDescriptorDacl((SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR*)pSecDescriptorBuf,
                                         &bDaclPresent, &pacl, &bDaclDefaulted);

    // Check if we successfully retrieved DACL
    if (!bSuccess)
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        cout << "Failed to retrieve DACL from security descriptor (" << dwError 
<< ")\n";
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    // Check if DACL present in security descriptor
    if (!bDaclPresent)
    {
        cout << "DACL was not found.\n";
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    // DACL for specified file was retrieved successfully
    // Now, we should fill in the linked list of ACEs
    // Iterate through ACEs (Access Control Entries) of DACL
    for (USHORT i = 0; i < pacl->AceCount; i++)
    {
        LPVOID pAce;
        bSuccess = GetAce(pacl, i, &pAce);
        if (!bSuccess)
        {
            DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
            cout << "Failed to get ace " << i << " (" << dwError << ")\n";
            continue;
        }
        BYTE AceFlags = ((ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE*)pAce)->Header.AceFlags;
        BOOL Inherited = (AceFlags && (INHERITED_ACE || OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE || CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE)) != 0;
        if (!Inherited)  
          cout << "not ";
        cout << "Inherited";

    }

    return 0;
}
```

AceFlags is always 0 for the affected files. So what is the correct way to determine that these ACLs are inherited?

Comment: Microsoft meanwhile confirmed to me that this is a bug in these API calls and recommends using alternative APIs like `GetNamedSecurityInfo()`